# Graphics card and dual monitors are not functioning correctly

Tags: windows-8.1, display, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I got a new EVGA GTX 970 graphics card and plugged 2 devices into it. The first is a 27" monitor that is using VGA to DVI to connect to the GPU, and the other is a 32" tv which is connected to the GPU via HDMI. Both displays are detected but it seems like the desktop space is offset between the displays. My main display seems to actually be taking up part of my second display, as one column of icons is on the main display and one column is on the secondary, and when I move windows between the displays, it resizes part of the way after actually moving between monitors. Has anyone had this problem before?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Solution :

It's a common problem on certain screens most screen have a feature to readjust the display called "Auto Adjustment".

Just check the menu of your second screen and look for that option.

Otherwise if you screen does not have the feature, check your graphical card application "EVGA Config Tools" or so, you should have a feature to adjust the screen.

Note : This is not possible with native windows configuration screen

## Capture :

You should have something like this to adjust it [Capture](http://webpages.charter.net/lhaas9941/nvidia%20position%20size.JPG)

Comment: My monitor has an auto adjust and it did not help. The TV does not have an auto adjust. I played with the nvidia display settings and it didn't help.

Comment: i edited my answer... the main screen is intended to display a computer so the calibration is useless most time...

Comment: you can also try to switch the screens, connect the main one with hdmi and tv with vga/dvi